# How To pre populate Html form field with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to pre fill my html form field "Reference" from url  value for referne is afer ref?=1234  how to do it with laravel

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="block" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div style="width: 100%" class="alert alert-warning">
                                    Please Register With a Reference User.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="reference" value="HERE WANT TO SHOW REFEERENCE CODE FROM URL" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Reference ID *" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i></span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like:

```
<input type="text" name="reference" value="{{ app('request')->input('ref') }}" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Reference ID *" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `request()` helper:

```
$ref = request('ref'); // It will return 1234.
```

Comment: @WaqarAli whatever you like. It works in views, controllers etc. `request('ref')` will give you `1234`. In this case, you need to put it into `value="{{ request('ref') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `$GET` variable in PHP.

There is a [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/pl/reserved.variables.get.php).

In laravel, you may use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input) facade or [Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input) facade

so here:

```
<input value="view{{ \Request::get('ref') }}" type="text" name="reference" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Reference ID *" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

// http://localhost/codec/register?ref=g5M089zQeVzc
// will produce
// <input value="viewg5M089zQeVzc" ...
```

Comment: is it suitable with laravel

Comment: i am talking about laravel not php

Comment: it ispopulating form with "view"  not referrence code

Comment: are you sure you have `?reference=234` in your address?

Comment: http://localhost/codec/register?ref=g5M089zQeVzc this link and i want to populate filed with words after "=" or equal sign in url

Comment: see, you are using `ref` not `reference` I've updated my answer to reflect you later changes and modifications to your question.